# Reed-Solomon Parity dilemma: Data shard vs Parity Shard

Tags: cluster-computing

Assuming a cluster of `60 drives over 5 nodes` with each node holding 12 drives.

What is safer?

> 6 drives data shards + 2 parity shards = 8 drives

vs

> 8 drives data shards + 2 parity shards = 10 drives

vs

> 9 drives data shards + 3 parity shards = 12 drives

vs

> 16 drives data shards + 4 parity shards = 20 drives

- What is better approach to protect against single disk failure?
- What is better approach to protect against single node failure?

Also, if you were to build this mini cluster, what parity would you go for?

Which of the two configurations above is more:

- Durable?
- Robust?

BTW, I am using ceph on this with bluestore. Please feel free to criticize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I am going to add another node to the cluster and then run 8+2 per node to maximise the durability and availability.

The chances of failure of a single node are 1 in 6 and even if a node goes down. It will take down 8 data + 2 parity shards with it.

In CEPH the data could be distributed so that no node has more than 2 data of parity shards for a piece of data.

This will allow for a node to go down and at max take down 2 parity shards or 2 data shards. This although will put stress on the system for rebuilding the parities, it is fairly safe.

The safer option would to go down to 6 + 2 but that wastes too much data for my use case.

I would have posted probabilities but they are done in excel and I don't know how to upload excel here.